# Null keyword added to couchbase exceptions with spring 2.6.6

Tags: java, spring, junit, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

Hi I am using Couchbase Java SDK 3.2.6 with Spring 2.6.6 and junit5
When some exception thrown in tests, all of them are failing becuase "null" keyword added at the end of exception message.

Test

```
import com.couchbase.client.core.error.DocumentNotFoundException;
import com.couchbase.client.core.error.context.ErrorContext;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvSource;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TaskServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private TaskService taskService;

    @Mock
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @Test
    void shouldThrowDocumentNotFoundExceptionWithGettingTaskByIdForFindTaskById() {
        //Given
        var exceptionMessage = "Document with the given id not found";
        var wrongTaskId = "12345678";

        when(taskRepository.findTaskById(wrongTaskId)).thenThrow(new DocumentNotFoundException(mock(ErrorContext.class)));

        //When
        var exception = assertThrows(DocumentNotFoundException.class, () -> taskService.getTaskDetail(wrongTaskId));

        //Then
        assertEquals(exceptionMessage, exception.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

errorMessage

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :Document with the given id not found
Actual   :Document with the given id not found null
```

Edit:

In the `CouchbaseExceptions` class this `getMessage` method returns proper error message + null

```
  public CouchbaseException(String message, Throwable cause, ErrorContext ctx) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public final String getMessage() {
        String output = super.getMessage();
        return this.ctx != null ? output + " " + this.ctx.exportAsString(ExportFormat.JSON) : output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The exceptions have had a context added to them.  Your mock ErrorContext doesn't implement exportAsString() therefore it evaluates to null.